# Arredondar valores 10,34 para números inteiros... Ex: 10 - Não funciona com scroll infinito

Tags: javascript

Estou aqui quebrando a cabeça para solucionar uma dificuldade que estou enfrentando, por isso vim pedir uma ajuda de vocês.

Minha plataforma tem aquele problema de apresentar números quebrados (ex: 10,42 % OFF) no % de desconto do produto.

Pesquisando na internet, encontrei uma função JS que parecia ter resolvido o caso, mas resolveu parcialmente, pois quando a página carrega mais produtos (próxima página), o js não funciona e o números permanecem com casa decimais após a vírgula.

Creio que isso tenha alguma relação com a questão do site ter scroll infinito... como não entendo de JS, não consigo encontrar uma solução.

Será que podem me ajudar?!

```
function limparClasse(classe) {
var elementos = document.querySelectorAll('.' + classe);
for (var i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
    var elemento = elementos[i];
    var string = elemento.innerHTML;
    var novaString = string.split('%');
    var arredondamento = parseInt(novaString[0], 10);
    var resultado = arredondamento + '%' + novaString[1];
    elemento.innerHTML = resultado;
}
```

}

limparClasse('vtex-cpShow');

Comment: Guilherme, esse tópico que você enviou não tem nada a ver com minha pergunta

Comment: O que falta na sua pergunta são exemplos práticos e maiores explicações. Aí cai no genérico, como marcado como duplicata.

Comment: Mais fácil usar o Math.round(). Ai já arredonda e não deve dar mais problemas.

Comment: @AntoniusLourençoKasbergen boa tarde... consegue me mostrar um exemplo na prática com o math.round ?